# Using Ramanujan-type "Legendrian" sequences to find new formulas for $\frac1{\pi}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, modular-forms, recurrences, ramanujan

**I. Recurrences**

(Continued from [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/447740/12905).) In Cooper's 2012 paper, "*[Sporadic sequences, modular forms and new series for 1/π](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257642843_Sporadic_sequences_modular_forms_and_new_series_for_1p)*", he did a computer search for the recurrence relation,

$$(n+1)^3 u_{n+1} = (2n+1)(an^2+an+b)u_n + n(\color{red}c\,n^2+d)u_{n-1}$$

and found three solutions. But with a bound of $|\color{red}c|<200$, he missed the following four,

\begin{align}
(n+1)^3 \alpha_{n+1} &= (2n+1)(1728n^2+1728n+\color{blue}{744})\alpha_n - (1728/2)^2 n(4n^2-1)\alpha_{n-1}\\[6pt]
(n+1)^3 \beta_{n+1} &= (2n+1)(256n^2+256n+\color{blue}{104})\beta_n - (256/2)^2 n(4n^2-1)\beta_{n-1}\\[6pt]
(n+1)^3 \gamma_{n+1} &= (2n+1)(108n^2+108n+\color{blue}{42})\gamma_n - (108/2)^2 n(4n^2-1)\gamma_{n-1}\\[6pt]
(n+1)^3 \delta_{n+1} &= (2n+1)(64n^2+64n+\color{blue}{24})\delta_n - (64/2)^2 n(4n^2-1)\delta_{n-1}\\
\end{align}

These four allow for new series for 1/π. The blue numbers may be familiar. Recall the approximations,

\begin{align}
e^{(\pi/1)\sqrt{163}} &\approx 640320^3 + \color{blue}{743}.99999999999925\\
e^{(\pi/2)\sqrt{232}} &\approx 396^4-\color{blue}{104}.0000001\\
e^{(\pi/3)\sqrt{267}} &\approx 300^3+\color{blue}{41}.99997\\
e^{(\pi/4)\sqrt{112}} &\approx 2^{12}-\color{blue}{24}.06
\end{align}

where $d=163, 232, 267$ are discriminants with [class number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) $h(-d) = 1,2,2$ respectively, and the divisor of $\pi$ indicates the level of the *McKay-Thompson series* or modular form involved.

---

**II. Sequences**

Given binomial $\binom{n}{m}$. Then the following satisfy the recurrences above,

\begin{align}
\alpha_n &= (-1)^n\binom{2n}n\sum_{j=0}^n(-432)^{n-j}\binom{n}j\binom{3j}j\binom{6j}{3j}\\
&=1, 744, 891864, 1218154560,\dots\\[6pt]
\beta_n &= (-1)^n\binom{2n}n\sum_{j=0}^n(-64)^{n-j}\binom{n}j\binom{2j}{j}\binom{4j}{2j}\\
&=1, 104, 17880, 3536960,\dots \\[6pt]
\gamma_n &= (-1)^n\binom{2n}n\sum_{j=0}^n(-27)^{n-j}\binom{n}j\binom{2j}{j}\binom{3j}{j}\\
&=1, 42, 2970, 243420,\dots\\[6pt]
\delta_n &= (-1)^n\binom{2n}n\sum_{j=0}^n(-16)^{n-j}\binom{n}j\binom{2j}{j}\binom{2j}{j}\\
&=1, 24, 984, 47040,\dots\\
\end{align}

with all $s_0 = 1$. *Note*: Without its binomial factor, these yield,

\begin{align}
a_n &=1, 372, 148644, 60907728,\dots\\[4pt]
b_n &=1, 52, 2980, 176848,\dots\\[4pt]
c_n &=1, 21, 495, 12171,\dots\\[4pt]
d_n &=1, 12, 164, 2352,\dots
\end{align}

with only the last two found by Zagier in [his 2009 paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/43796518_Integral_solutions_of_Apery-like_recurrence_equations), namely $c_n = Sequence \text{#}25$ and $d_n = Sequence \text{#}19$, from the table in page 3.

Together with $Sequence \text{#}26$ (related to $d_n$), he called the three as "*Legendrian solutions*". But the first two sequences $(a_n, b_n)$ had parameters beyond his search radius, and easily checked as not being in the table. And only $d_n$ is in the OEIS as [A143583](https://oeis.org/A143583).

---

**III. Pi formulas**

To get new pi formulas, we use a special case of Method 2 from [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446886/12905),

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_1(n) \frac{An+B}{C^n}=\left(\frac{C}{C+4r}\right)^{3/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n S_2(n)\frac{An+B+D_2}{(C+4r)^n}$$

where,

$$D_2 =\frac{-2r\,(A-2B)}{C}$$

with $S_1(n)$ as any of Ramanujan's four original sequences and $S_2(n)$ as the ***matching*** sequence $(\alpha_n,\,\beta_n,\,\gamma_n,\,\delta_n)$, and $r = -432,-64,-27,-16$, respectively.

---

**IV. Examples**

**A.** For level-2, the matching sequence is $\beta_n$ and $r=-64$. Thus from,

$$\frac{2\sqrt2}{99^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}^2\binom{4n}{2n}\,\frac{26390n+1103}{(396^4)^n}=\frac1{\pi}$$

one gets the new,

$$\frac{99^4}{\big(910\sqrt{58}\big)^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \beta_n\,\frac{26390n+1103+12092/99^4}{(396^4-256)^n}=\frac1{\pi}$$

**B.** For level-4, the matching sequence is $\delta_n$ and $r=-16$. Thus from,

$$\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}^3\,\frac{42n+5}{\quad(2^{12})^n}=\frac1{\pi}$$

one gets,

$$\frac{32}{\big(3\sqrt{7}\big)^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \delta_n\,\frac{42n+5+1/4}{(2^{12}-64)^n}=\frac1{\pi}$$

and so on for levels 1 and 3. I believe the second example was also found experimentally (but in a slightly different form) by Almkvist in his [2012 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6563).

---

**V. Question**

1. As long as the series converges, so why does the transformation work?
2. And why did Zagier seemingly dismiss his Legendrian solutions when, just like his sporadic sequences, some (maybe not all) have a modular form context and related to eta quotients (like in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/447740/12905))?